# Visual Studio automatically updating assembly references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, project-reference, assembly-reference-path

Solution A has a project which builds an assembly, which is referenced by a project in Solution B.

Solution A builds to c:\Bob, and solution B references the assembly c:\Bob\Assembly1.dll, and builds to C:\Kate\, copying Assembly1.dll to c:\Kate\

If Solution A is rebuilt (whilst solution B is open in Visual Studio), the reference to Assembly1.dll in Solution B is temporarily broken, and visual studio tries to automatically resolve this by updating the reference from c:\Bob\Assmebly1.dll, to c:\Kate\Assembly1.dll (Which is now the incorrect reference).

Can this behaviour be disabled?

The projects cannot be hosted within the same solution, I must use assembly references due to the size and complexity of the project.

Comment: Try to delete your file `myassembly.dll.refresh`. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089165/what-is-a-dll-refresh-file-in-asp-net

Comment: NuGet is a possible solution to your problem. I use it even when developing for solving problems such as "assembly references due to the size and complexity of the project". Especially useful when working in a team, avoid forcing others to open and recompile solutions they depend on. No need for a server, just publish into a folder